# перестал работать pdo execute()

Tags: php, pdo

После переустановки open server, перестал работать метод `execute()` php7.

запрос:

```
$sql = 'SELECT count(*) as count FROM records WHERE hiddenRecord = 0';
```

массив поступающий в функцию `SqlExecute()` пустой.

функция обработки:

```
private function SqlExecute($sql = '', $array = [])
{
    if($sql != '')
    {
        $Query = $this->Connect();

        if($Query != null)
        {
            $Query->prepare($sql);

            foreach($array as $key => $str)
            {
                if(is_numeric($str))
                {
                    $Query->bindParam($key, $array[$key], PDO::PARAM_INT);
                }
                elseif(is_string($str))
                {
                    $Query->bindParam($key, $array[$key], PDO::PARAM_STR);
                }
            }

            $Query->execute();

            if($Query->rowCount() > 0)
            {
                return [
                    'count' => $Query->rowCount(),
                    'lastId' => $this->Connect()->lastInsertId(),
                    'result' => $Query,
                    'status' => true,
                ];
            }
            else
            {
                return [
                    'count' => 0,
                    'lastId' => 0,
                    'result' => '',
                    'status' => false,
                ];
            }
        }
    }
    return [
        'count' => 0,
        'status' => false,
    ];
}

// Соединение.
private function Connect()
{
    static $ini__li;

    if($ini__li === null)
    {
        try
        {
            $ini__li = new PDO(
                $this->base,
                $this->user,
                $this->pass
            );

            $ini__li->exec('SET NAMES UTF8');
        }
        catch(PDOException $e)
        {
            $ini__li = null;
        }

    }
    return $ini__li;
}
```

Выводимая ошибка

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method PDO::execute()

Comment: у коннекшена есть `exec` у statement есть `execute`. у вас же тут объект из первого, и метод из второго

Comment: @teran так.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$Query = $this->Connect();
```

Здесь вы создаете объект [PDO](http://php.net/manual/ru/class.pdo.php).

далее подготавливаете выражение

```
$Query->prepare($sql);
```

Данное выражение возвращает экземпляр [`PDOStatement`](http://php.net/manual/ru/class.pdostatement.php).
Далее вы пытаетесь приложить методы `bindParam` и `execute` к объекту `PDO`, хотя должны сделать что-то вроде

```
$stmt = $Query->prepare($sql); 
$stmt->bindParam(...)
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: Чертовщина, почему раньше это работало?